# Array assignment operation question

Tags: java

If I have a piece of code like this:

```
MyClass[] objArray = new MyClass[7];
//assign values to objArray
//do something here
//sometime later
MyClass newObj = new MyClass();
objArray[3] = newObj;
```

The last statement above will do the following:

- copy all the contents of the `newObj` to the space referred to by objArray[3].

#### Questions

1. Am I right?
2. Shallow copy or deep copy?
3. If it is shallow copy, how can I make the deep copy possible?

   ```
   objArray[3] = newObj;
   ```
4. Does this rule applies to other Java container types, such as Queue, List, ...?

Comment: No copy of the object, just of the reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer 1&2: No. Only a reference to the object is copied. `newObj` and `objArray[3]` will afterwards refer to the same object instance.

Answer 3: If you want a copy, you have to implement it yourself. You could implement a copy constructor or `Clonable`, or for a simple deep copy, serialize and deserialize the object, but that requires it and all objects it consists of to be `Serializable`

Answer 4: It's exactly the same for all Java Objects: the reside on the heap, and the code works only with references to the objects. Container types usually implement a copy constructor that does a shallow copy. There is no deep copy functionality that is automatically available for all classes.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it *will* copy "all the contents of the `newObj`" into `objArray[3]`... **but** the contents (or value) of the `newObj` variable is *just* a reference to the object. In other words, consider:

```
objArray[3] = newObj;
newObj.setFoo("hello");

System.out.println(objArray[3].getFoo()); // prints "hello"
```

(assuming a simple property, of course).

Basically, the value of a variable (including array elements) is *never* an object. It's *always* a reference or a primitive value. It's *always* passed or copied by value.

Comment: Great example to illustrate how Arrays reference an object!

Answer (score 2):

1. No, it does not copy the content. It just creates another reference.
2. Shallow. (See 1)
3. You cannot use that statement if you want a deep copy. You have to override the clone-method of java.lang.Object in your Class `MyClass` and use that or create copy constructor.
4. It applies to all data types that are not primitives like int or double;

Answer (score 1):

> copy all the contents of the newObj to
>   the space referred by objArray[3].

Nope, it will store a reference to [the Object referenced by: *thanks Jon Skeet*] newObj at objArray[3]. The original object is not changed or copied in any way, just the reference to it.

Comment: Note that `newObj` isn't an object - it's a variable. It's important to distinguish the two, as giving a new value to `newObj` doesn't change what's in the array at all.

Answer (score 1):

no copy at all. The reference to the object is set in the array.